# OpenCV выбрасывает Exception

Tags: java, intellij-idea, opencv

Собирался начать изучение библиотеки OpenCV на JAVA, в Idea. Скачал с оффсайта библиотеку, распаковал и добавил jar в либы. Код успешно импотрировался, методы появились но при попытке запустить код выдаёт:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no opencv_java300 in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1864)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
    at Solution.main(Solution.java:11)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

Comment: Скорее всего у вас не соответствует разрядность библиотеки.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте сделать так:

```
@BeforeClass
public void setUp(){
    System.loadLibrary("lib/x64/opencv_java300");
}

@Test
public void openCVTest(){
    System.out.println("OpenCV configuration simple test:");
    Mat m = Mat.eye(3,3, CvType.CV_8UC1);
    System.out.println("OpenCV matrix = " + m.dump());
}


public class App {

    static{ System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME); }

    public static void main( String[] args ){
        System.out.println("OpenCV configuration simple test:");
        Mat m = Mat.eye(3,3, CvType.CV_8UC1);
        System.out.println("OpenCV matrix = " + m.dump());
    }

 }
```

Comment: что значит @BeforeClass и что с этим делать?

Comment: Это junit. How to use можно найти тут: http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/junit/junit-before-and-beforeclass-example/

Comment: Та же ошибка, что и в прошлый раз.

Comment: @ВадимПотапов вы уверены, что по указанному вами пути есть opencv? Если он там есть, разрядность x64?

Comment: там должна быть opencv_java300.jar же ?

Comment: да, там должен быть Jarник